# How to extract the String URL label and retrieve parent and grandparent path

Tags: java, string, url, label

I want to extract the String URL label and retrieve parent and grandparent path from string

String url="ricsglobal:content/category/news-and-insight/type/wbef";

I want to check depth of this URL and want to find the grandparent path like this "ricsglobal:content/category/news-and-insight".

Comment: What did you try to extract those paths from the string which already contains a path/url? Btw, you might want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Convert your string to URI, then use [resolve("../..")](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html#resolve(java.lang.String)).